# In Sublime Text, how do I find and replace the file name

Tags: linux, unix, sublimetext2

Is there a way in sublime text where I can find a pattern and replace it with file names.

For example,
I have  a bunch of file names that contain people.

I want to replace that with person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Menu: `Find -> Find in Files...`

Sublime is gonna open a new panel at the bottom, you just need to fill the fields. Inside the field Where, you can, for example, look up only for .txt files:

```
Find: People
Where: C:\Temp, *.txt
Replace: Person
```

Comment: this is for content of files, not file names

Answer (score 4):

in `SideBarEnhancements` there is an option to `Mass Rename Selection...` under `Find Advanced` to batch rename multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer could be outdated**

- Install the `SideBarEnhancements` plugin
- Select the folder from the bar
- Right-click and open the context menu
- From `Find Advanced` -> `Mass Rename Selection...` you can do this.

[image]

Comment: For me this feature is bugged (at least for ST4). When I do mass rename, it does create new directories/files, but in case of directory it leaves old name directory as empty one. So basically duplicating and leaving traces of the old dirs

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do a find and replace on a filename. Although there is a great package called SideBarEnhancements which would benefit from this feature. I will definitely submit a feature request.