# How to replace html code in multiple files with SublimeText using regular expression?

Tags: html, regex, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Im using Sublime Text. Quite lost with regex. I have multiple html files with:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" type="text/css">
</head>
```

Where code should be changed to:

```
<head>
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/catalog/example_unic.html" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" type="text/css">
</head>
```

And each `href="http:/example.com/catalog/example_unic.html"` should be changed to current page name. How I can achieve this result? I ve followed this thread [regular expression search replace in Sublime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076075/regular-expression-search-replace-in-sublime) but did't get the result I need.

Comment: Would you mind presenting those regexes? So the people can take it up where you struggled.
Also your canonical href needs an additional slash for the http. but basically:
Search For
href\=\"http\:\/example\.com\/catalog\/example_unic.html\"
Should be working if you're escaping it correctly...
Also where does the page name come from?

Comment: Its almost the same what you ve wrote. You are right, I ve missed second slash, my bad, eagleeye eh. Page name probably should come from file name which we get from searched folder/destination, this is a part whic I dont uderstand.

Comment: As far as i see, you cannot get the filename for replacement: 

https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/how-do-i-get-a-files-name-for-use-in-a-search-replace/25086/2
or in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064977/in-sublime-text-how-do-i-find-and-replace-the-file-name

best i can come up with is 
searching for: <head>\n(.*)\n</head>
replacing with: <head>\n<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/catalog/file.html" />\n$1\n</head>

where you'll change the filename per replacement :/

or look into the second link, i guess a batch / ps script could work pretty well too.